Switching from async to sync mode caused apps to freeze
SQL server 2022 enterprise edition AG is currently in async mode.
This is a 2 node AG, 32 cpu, 275GB RAM server dedicated for each SQL server. Both nodes reside in the same data center with fibre network.
This morning at about 8am, using the AG properties, I changed the mode from async to sync.
This caused all the client applications to halt for about 5mins, and there were  blockings, untill I switched the AG back to async mode, then everything went back to normal.
Upon reviewing the SQL wait stats for those 5mins, I can see that HADR_SYNC_COMMIT avg wait time was 2000ms, LCK_M_SCH_S was 95575ms, and LCK_M_U was 85644ms.
What could have caused this behaviour? What precautions can I take next time when performing this action as I would like the AG to ideally be in sync mode.
Note: not sure if this adds any value, but there was reporting workload hitting the readable secondary node during that time.
This has been tested in dev environment for similar workload. We also run such synchronous AGs for several 2 node SQL servers. I'm just looking for help on what can I focus on to identify root cause. I don't understand why avg wait time for hadr sync commit went up to 2 seconds (2000ms) during that window. Most likely that caused the other LCK waits to spike. The only significant wait on secondary is the redo pending wait (35ms), otherwise nothing. I'm reading articles that say when a heavy transaction is running on primary then it takes a while for secondary to build the temp db row versioning until it is able to actually switch to the sync mode. But this doesn't explain why primary has high hadr sync commit (of 2000ms that is 2s per transaction), and blockings.
I have much heavier AG servers having 10 times higher workload in terms of CPU and disk IO and this issue doesn't show up on those servers. I'm trying to understand what can I look into further before re attempting the change from async to sync mode.
Note: The issue has resolved itself next week when I attempted this.


What could have caused this behaviour?

That's how sync commit works, nothing can move on until the changes are safe on each replica whereas async does not. This is explained in the Docs quite well and could have answered your question. I'd suggest reading up on AGs given the number of questions posted here which are answered by reading the documentation.
